# How to display Order id in paypal transaction detail page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, activemerchant

we are using rails4 , activemerchant 1.47.0 .

Normally, order id is not showing in transaction detail page for a transaction of a order in paypal.

**How can we set the order id in transaction detail page of a paypal transaction ?**

These are the methods used for a transaction and purchase.

```
 response = ACTIVE_GATEWAY.setup_purchase((payment.amount * 100),
                                           ip: request.remote_ip,
                                           return_url: "url",
                                           cancel_return_url: url,
                                           currency: "USD",
                                           items: [{name: order.number, description: "Order description", quantity: "1", amount: (payment.amount * 100)}]
  )
  redirect_to ACTIVE_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
```

**Purchase**

```
 purchase_response = ACTIVE_GATEWAY.purchase((payment.amount* 100), {
            :ip => request.remote_ip,
            :token => token,
            :payer_id => payerID
        })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

This is for development environment.

config/development.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
    paypal_options = {
        :login => "email_id",
        :password => "password",
        :signature => "signature"
    }
    ::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(paypal_options)
end
```

Controller::

```
def express_paypal
    order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
    amount = order.total_amount
    response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(amount,
        :ip                => request.remote_ip,
        :return_url        => url_for(:action => 'complete', :id => order.id),
        :cancel_return_url => url_for(:action => 'show', :controller => "orders",:id => order.id),
        :allow_guest_checkout => true,
        :items =>
            [{ :name => current_user.to_s,
            :quantity => 1,
            :description => "Items",
            :amount => amount
            }]
        )
    if response.present?
        redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
    end
end


def complete   
    order = current_user.orders.find(params[:id])
    amount = order.total_amount
    begin
     purchase = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(amount,
            :ip       => request.remote_ip,
            :payer_id => params[:PayerID],
            :token    => params[:token]
        )
    rescue Exception => e
        logger.error "Paypal error while creating payment: #{e.message}"
        flash[:error] = e.message
    end
    unless purchase.success?
        flash[:error] = "Unfortunately an error occurred:" + purchase.message
    else
        flash[:notice] = "Thank you for your payment"
    end
  redirect_to :action => "show", :id => order.id
end
```

Comment: It did not mark the order id in transaction detail page.